# How to post a Pandas DataFrame using API in Django

Tags: django, pandas, django-rest-framework

Currently I send one post request per DataFrame's row, which means that I read the row, convert it to Json data and send it using `request.post`.
Is there any better way to send the entire data frame in one post request?

Thanks,

Comment: It would be nice to add your code and problem so that the solution is more clear. It will safe and help many people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried converting the entire dataframe to a python dictionary and then sending it as json. Try pandas to_dict() method. Just call df.to_dict() method on your dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

you can use rest-pandas package. documentation can be found here.
https://pypi.org/project/rest-pandas/